# How can you write an R code to print a number pattern in rows such as the following:

Tags: r

What functions would you need to use to write a program in R to print the following for n rows:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2 3
[1] 4 5 6
[1] 7 8 9 10
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
[1] ....
```

I have tried using `for()` to create a loop:

```
triangle=c()
for(i in 2:100){for(j in 2:i-1){triangle=c(triangle,j)}
print(triangle) 
triangle=c()}
```

but each line starts on 1 and ends at 100 rows which is where I am stuck.

I am a beginner in R so please answer in the simplest terms! :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure when do you want to break the loop but here is an attempt using `while` condition :

```
i <- 1
num <- 0
while(i <= 100) {
    n <- i + num
    cat(i:n, '\n')
    i <- n + 1
    num <- num + 1
}

1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 
67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 
79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 
92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105
```

This prints until the first number in the sequence is less than equal to 100.

---

To print alternate reverse sequence :

```
i <- 1
num <- 0
while(i <= 100) {
  n <- i + num
  if(num %% 2 == 0) cat(n:i, '\n')
  else cat(i:n, '\n')
  i <- n + 1
  num <- num + 1
}

1 
2 3 
6 5 4 
7 8 9 10 
15 14 13 12 11 
16 17 18 19 20 21 
28 27 26 25 24 23 22 
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 
45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 
66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 
67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 
91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80 79 
92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105
```

Comment: Does the 'while' condition make it possible to integrate a reversal of alternate lines into the pattern? i.e. 
# 1
# 2 3
# 6 5 4
# 7 8 9 10
# 15 14 13 12 11
# ... 

If so/not, which functions would enable this?

Answer (score 2):

Or another possibility using `sum(1:n)=n*(n+1)/2`

```
for (n in 1:10) {
  print(seq((n-1) * n / 2  + 1 , n * (n+1) / 2))
}

[1] 1
[1] 2 3
[1] 4 5 6
[1] 7  8  9 10
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21
[1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
[1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
[1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
[1] 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
[1] 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
```

or reversed every second line:

```
for (n in 1:10) {
  if (n%%2 ==1) {
    print(seq((n-1)*n/2+1 , n*(n+1)/2))
  } else {
    print(seq(n*(n+1)/2, (n-1)*n/2+1 ))
  }
}

[1] 1
[1] 3 2
[1] 4 5 6
[1] 10  9  8  7
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
[1] 21 20 19 18 17 16
[1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
[1] 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29
[1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 46
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't clear on whether you want rows until the row that contains 100 or whether you want 100 rows.  Below I have assumed the first of these but if you want 100 rows remove the line that sets k and replace the computation of n (which we derive from k) with `n <- 100`.

**1)** n rows can accommodate numbers up to k = choose(n+1, 2) = n*(n+1)/2 so using k=100 and inverting the [quadratic](https://www.mathsisfun.com/quadratic-equation-solver.html) 0.5 * n^2 + 0.5 * n - k we derive n.  Then use `rep` to create a grouping vector `g` equal to `c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...)`  Finally split `seq_along(g)` by `g`.

```
k <- 100  # input

n <- ceiling((-.5 + sqrt(.5^2 - 4*.5*(-k))) / (2*.5))  # no of rows

# if you want 100 rows instead of rows until 100 
#   remove lines above and uncomment next line
# n <- 100  
g <- rep(1:n, 1:n)
s <- split(seq_along(g), g)
s
```

giving this list:

```
$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 2 3

$`3`
[1] 4 5 6

$`4`
[1]  7  8  9 10

$`5`
[1] 11 12 13 14 15

$`6`
[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21

$`7`
[1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

$`8`
[1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

$`9`
[1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45

$`10`
 [1] 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55

$`11`
 [1] 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66

$`12`
 [1] 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78

$`13`
 [1] 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91

$`14`
 [1]  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105
```

**2)** Another possibility, using n from above, is:

```
m <- NA * diag(n)
t(replace(m, upper.tri(m, TRUE), 1:choose(n+1, 2)))
```

giving this matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
 [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [2,]    2    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [3,]    4    5    6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [4,]    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [5,]   11   12   13   14   15   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [6,]   16   17   18   19   20   21   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [7,]   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [8,]   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [9,]   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[10,]   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54    55    NA    NA    NA    NA
[11,]   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64    65    66    NA    NA    NA
[12,]   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75    76    77    78    NA    NA
[13,]   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87    88    89    90    91    NA
[14,]   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100   101   102   103   104   105
```

Comment: Regarding reversing every second row, if `s` is as in the answer then `s[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- lapply(s[c(TRUE, FALSE)], rev)`

Answer (score 1):

purrr style

```
imap(1:10, ~seq.int((.x-1)*.x/2 +1, length.out = .y))

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[4]]
[1]  7  8  9 10

[[5]]
[1] 11 12 13 14 15

[[6]]
[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21

[[7]]
[1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

[[8]]
[1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

[[9]]
[1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45

[[10]]
 [1] 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
```

Or some concatenated style if it'd be useful

```
imap_chr(1:10, ~ paste(seq.int((.x-1)*.x/2 +1, length.out = .y), collapse = " "))

 [1] "1"                            
 [2] "2 3"                          
 [3] "4 5 6"                        
 [4] "7 8 9 10"                     
 [5] "11 12 13 14 15"               
 [6] "16 17 18 19 20 21"            
 [7] "22 23 24 25 26 27 28"         
 [8] "29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36"      
 [9] "37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45"   
[10] "46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55"
```

Comment: You know I decided to take a break from `purrr` functions for this one :))))

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**
There was a minor glitch in my code that I just fixed.

Here is another way of producing your desired result. I decided to turn it into a function so you can choose the number of rows:

```
f <- function(n = 10) {
  out <- c(1)
  print(out)
  
  for(i in 2:n) {
    result <- seq(out[length(out)] + 1, length = i)
    out <- c(out, result)
    print(result)
  }
}

f(15)

[1] 1
[1] 2 3
[1] 4 5 6
[1] 7  8  9 10
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21
[1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
[1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
[1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
[1] 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
[1] 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
[1] 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78
[1] 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91
[1] 92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105
[1] 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
```